# CORS on WCF - Why specify web server when request is from client machine?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, wcf, cors

To allow an HTTP GET request to a WCF service, I had to allow the web server access by doing this in the WCF method:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", webServer);
```

Why does that work? The request is coming from the client browser, not the web server.

**Load Page**
Client -- HTTP --> WebServer

**Make WCF Request**
Client -- HTTP --> WCF Service

I used Wireshark to check the traffic on the WCF server. It's indeed coming from the client machine where the user has the web page open. It's not coming from the web server. So why does specifying the web server in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` work when the traffic isn't coming from the web server?

If it helps, this is the call in JavaScript:

```
    var config = {
        url: 'http://WcfServerName:8000/MmaWebApiService/CreateCassette',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { 'moduleSerialNumbers': [$scope.state.subId1, $scope.state.subId2, $scope.state.subId3] }
    };

    $http(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            addCassetteToStack(response.data.d);
            $rootScope.setUserMessage('Cassette ' + response.data.d.SerialNumber + ' created.');
        }, function (response) {
            console.log('err: ', response);
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the type of webServer is in the code provided or what the properties are so I'm making a few assumptions. Generally the WCF server is your protected resource and it is at that level that you should allow or deny access from different source domains such as your web server or javascript code. Even though your javascript call is made client side the request header should have your source domain in there which is used for the access control.

Comment: Ah, that's it! The header of my request shows the web server as the host. Thanks! If you'd like to post that as the answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the type of webServer is in the code provided or what the properties are so I'm making a few assumptions. Generally the WCF server is your protected resource and it is at that level that you should allow or deny access from different source domains such as your web server or javascript code. Even though your javascript call is made client side the request header should have your source domain in there which is used for the access control.